How to make a Chrome extension to download an image by one-click?
I am creating a Chrome extension that allows users to download images from the current webpage with a single click.
However, I encounter issues on some websites, such as Medium, where clicking the "Enable Image Download" button and then clicking an image results in the webpage navigating to the image URL instead of downloading the image.
How can I modify my code to prevent this behavior and ensure that images are downloaded when clicked?
Here is my current code:
// Check if chrome.scripting is available
if (chrome.scripting) {
  chrome.scripting.executeScript({
    target: { tabId: tabId },
    func: enableImageDownload
  }, (results) => {
    if (chrome.runtime.lastError) {
      console.error('Script injection failed: ' + chrome.runtime.lastError.message);
    } else {
      console.log('Script injection succeeded');
    }
  });
} else {
  console.error('chrome.scripting is not available');
}
});

// Function to handle image click and download
function enableImageDownload() {
  console.log('enableImageDownload function called'); // Debugging message
  
  // Add click event listener to all images on the page
  document.querySelectorAll('img').forEach(img => {
    img.style.border = "2px solid red"; // Add red border to highlight the image
    img.style.cursor = "pointer"; // Change cursor to pointer
  
    img.addEventListener("click", function handleClick(event) {
      console.log("Image clicked"); // Debugging message
  
      // Prevent default behavior
      event.preventDefault();
      event.stopPropagation();
  
      // Remove click event listener after the first click
      img.removeEventListener("click", handleClick);
  
      // Reset image border and cursor
      img.style.border = "";
      img.style.cursor = "";
  
      // Create anchor element to trigger download
      const a = document.createElement("a");
      a.href = img.src;
      a.download = img.src.split('/').pop().split('?')[0]; // Extract file name
      document.body.appendChild(a);
      a.click();
      document.body.removeChild(a);
      console.log("Image download triggered"); // Debugging message
    });
  });
}



Additional Details:
I am using Chrome's scripting API to inject the script that enables image downloading.
The script works correctly on most websites, but fails on sites like Medium where clicking an image navigates to the image URL.
I have tried using event.preventDefault() and event.stopPropagation(), but the issue persists.
What modifications are needed to ensure that images are downloaded correctly on all websites?

You need to get at the parent link - this SHOULD have worked but does not work on the Medium page - they likely have event handlers on the containers too.
if (link && link.parentNode) link.parentNode.replaceChild(img, link);

document.querySelectorAll('img').forEach(img => {
  img.style.border = "2px solid red"; // Add red border to highlight the image
  img.style.cursor = "pointer"; // Change cursor to pointer
  const link = img.closest('a');
  if (link && link.parentNode) link.parentNode.replaceChild(img, link);
  img.addEventListener("click", function handleClick(event) {
    console.log("Image clicked"); // Debugging message

    // Prevent default behavior
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();

    // Remove click event listener after the first click
    img.removeEventListener("click", handleClick);

    // Reset image border and cursor
    img.style.border = "";
    img.style.cursor = "";

    // Create anchor element to trigger download
    const a = document.createElement("a");
    a.href = img.src;
    a.download = img.src.split('/').pop().split('?')[0]; // Extract file name
    document.body.appendChild(a);
    a.click();
    document.body.removeChild(a);
    console.log("Image download triggered"); // Debugging message
  });
});

So instead extract the images and give them their own div
I will give you this code, it opens the image in a new tab, instead of downloading, but so does your original code. It could have something to do with the browser or some oversight.


const clickDownload = (event) => {
  const tgt = event.target;
  if (!tgt.matches('.download')) return;
  if (tgt.matches('.downloaded')) return;
  const src = tgt.src;
  console.log("Image clicked"); // Debugging message
  tgt.classList.add('downloaded')
  // Reset image border and cursor
  tgt.style.border = "";
  const a = document.createElement("a");
  a.href = src;
  a.download = src.split('/').pop().split('?')[0]; // Extract file name
  document.body.appendChild(a);
  a.click();
  document.body.removeChild(a);
};
const div = document.createElement('div');
div.addEventListener('click', clickDownload);
document.querySelectorAll('img').forEach(img => {
  const cloneImg = document.createElement('img');
  img.hidden = true;
  cloneImg.style.border = "2px solid red"; // Add red border to highlight the image
  cloneImg.style.margin = '3px';
  cloneImg.src = img.src;
  cloneImg.classList.add('download');
  div.appendChild(cloneImg);
});
document.body.appendChild(div);
<a href="..."><img src="https://placehold.co/100x200" /></a>
<a href="..."><img src="https://placehold.co/200x100" /></a>



